# What does JET mean in the Image Processing in Python_Final.ipynb tutorial?

Tags: python, image, fft, jet

I would like to ask a question regarding the
[Image Processing in Python_Final.ipynb tutorial](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/xn2333/OpenCV/blob/master/Image_Processing_in_Python_Final.ipynb#scrollTo=XUMXfKr5gMl9). In **Step6: Finding Edges by Highpass Filtering in FFT**, the third image is titled as **Result in JET**.
What does JET stand for?

Comment: Jet is a colormap. But that image uses the viridis colormap, not jet, so it is mislabeled. See here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223315/why-use-colormap-viridis-over-jet

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! Your answer is super helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

I seem to find the solution myself! From the code, it seems that JET is a kind of color map, and [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jet.html) is the link i found regarding the JET color map.